# Can't find the right screen dimension

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am running a fullscreen activity which includes notch too and I am unable to find screen's width and height.
I tried this:

```
val wm = getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE) as WindowManager
val display = wm.defaultDisplay
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()
display.getMetrics(metrics)
val width = metrics.widthPixels
val height = metrics.heightPixels
```

It returns a right width (1080) but a wrong height (2129 instead of 2340).
Whats the problem?

Comment: Looks to me like a full screen height minus status bar height.

Comment: Before I did `supportActionBar?.hide()` @M.Prokhorov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are querying an application area size, which might not take up the entire screen size. From `Display` class [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html):

> The application display area specifies the part of the display that may contain an application window, excluding the system decorations. The application display area may be smaller than the real display area because the system subtracts the space needed for decor elements such as the status bar. Use the following methods to query the application display area: **getSize(Point)**, **getRectSize(Rect)** and **getMetrics(DisplayMetrics)**

Right below, there's hint on how to get closer to what the physical display metrics are (note, however, that there are still cases when this will not return you the physical metrics of your display):

> The real display area specifies the part of the display that contains content including the system decorations. Even so, the real display area may be smaller than the physical size of the display if the window manager is emulating a smaller display using (adb shell wm size). Use the following methods to query the real display area: **getRealSize(Point)**, **getRealMetrics(DisplayMetrics)**

So your code should be:

```
val metrics = DisplayMetrics()

display.getRealMetrics(metrics)

val width = metrics.widthPixels
val height = metrics.heightPixels
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way of java code in kotlin

```
int width = ((Activity) mcontext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getWidth();

 int height= ((Activity) mcontext).getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay()
                    .getHeight();
```

hope it will help for you

Comment: Same problem and the getWidth()/getHeight() methods are deprecated